# How to draw 6 boxes and after the first 3 change the position of the final 3

Tags: java

I'm trying to draw 6 boxes with a for loop, i would like to have the first three boxes be drawn at a curtain x and y coordinate then after the first 3 have been drawn draw the final 3 at the same x coordinate but at a different y coordinate.

More detail:
Boxes have the same width and height
Would like to have 10 px of space between each
Needs to be repeatable for an infinite amount of boxes

```
for(int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
    bricks[i].setSize(size);
    if(i <= 2) {
        bricks[i].setPosition(i * (size + 10) + 180, 20);   
    }
    bricks[i].setState(Brickstate.WHITE);
}
```

Comment: What will be that different `y` coordinate?

Comment: i * the width of the boxes, + 10 for the spacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
    bricks[i].setSize(size);
    bricks[i].setPosition((i%3) * (size + 10) + 180, (i/3) * (ysize +10) + yOffset);   
    bricks[i].setState(Brickstate.WHITE);
}
```

By using i%3 instead of i the resulting x positions will be 0 1 2 0 1 2. They move over to the start when we go to the next line.
The y code i/3 will give us 0 0 0 1 1 1 therefore moving the last 3 boxes down by one.

Comment: Thank you so much! But there are two things i forgot to mention. I need the first boxes to start of at 20px. And i need to be able to have and infinite amount of boxes in the array list and still have it work correctly. I'm a big noob at this, so thanks for your time!